# HTTP Bad Request 400 WCF Soap Service in web cilent but not in chrome

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, google-chrome

I am confused as of why I am getting a bad request 400 in code using `Webclient.DownloadData` but not in chrome. I am just wondering if this is my web config file. Because the service can be found using Chrome (and everything works with the WCF test Client)

web.config

```
<services>
  <service name="MyWebService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
          <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyWebService.IService1"
          behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
  </service> 
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>


    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

```
 <ServiceContract()>
  Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract>
    <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate:="getData/{parameter}")>
    Function method(ByVal parameter As Integer) As String

  End Interface
```

and in the Webclient.DownloadData method

```
Webclient.DownloadData(http://localhost:61094/Service1.svc/getData/1)
```

(the address is of type Url)

I am getting a 400 in a catch.

Any ideas why the service is OK in the WCF test cilent and Chrome and not using webclient?

Extra infor: I am hosting the site in IIS EXPRESS in Visual Studio only

Comment: Can you show some code? What is the ServiceContract? Can you include the actual error message output? What is the request you're making when you get an error? Hard to diagnose when all I have is your web.config.

Comment: Just found out that if I unticked "show friendly HTTP errors" in IE settings, it does indeed work. Ok I will show service contract above, as I am getting the same 400 using the webcilent class now

Comment: Hopefully thats a bit more help. thanks

Comment: WebGet requires path parameters to be strings. `parameter` must be a string, not an integer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing SOAP and REST. REST is a method of using HTTP Verbs, status codes, and the URL path to make requests. In WCF, this is implemented using `WebGet` or `WebInvoke`. SOAP is 100% different than this. The parameters are passed to the service using a SOAP envelope. This is an XML based protocol. Essentially, a bunch of XML is sent in the request body representing a SOAP message. The response, likewise, is XML in the response body representing a SOAP message. Of course calling WebClient will not work. You're not sending a SOAP message. Instead, add a Service Reference to your WCF class. This will create a proxy class that can talk to your service. Right click on your Web References folder and choose `Add Service Reference`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) has information on the process.

But in any case, getData/1 will *never* work with SOAP because it's not SOAP, it's REST. Think of it this way, you walked up to someone who only speaks Chinese and started speaking to him in English. When he hears you, he hears gibberish (Hey's expecting Chinese). When he responds (probably saying I have no idea what you're saying), you hear gibberish (You're expecting English). Until you either both speak English (REST) or Chinese (SOAP), there will be no communication happening, just gibberish back and forth.

Comment: Thank you,  I do seem to remember reading that somewhere, however, I still get a 400 via code, and probably related, i get a blank screen on chrome and IE - no errors but no results, but WCF test client is still working well,

Comment: When you say the WCF client is working, it returns the XML from your message, or just no error? Please provide the entire WebException you're getting. You may also want to set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true while debugging. In any case, the change I suggested has to be made. WCF requires it to be a string. Integer will not work.

Comment: The WCF test Client returns the result I expect from the method call I do, I return a string so it just displays that.  When trying to replicate that in a browser, there is nothing, no results, no errors - just a blank screen. if I change the url on purpose it does then state the service cannot be found so I know it is found on load, but, I get nothing when entering http://localhost:61094/Service1.svc/getData/1

Comment: You said you're getting an error when using WebClient. Please include the actual WebException. Also, in IE consider using the network monitor in the F12 tools to see what the server is actually sending you. The raw HTTP output may prove very helpful.

Comment: The exception is 

{"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."} - nothing more in inner exception. and using f12 there no error codes, but again no XML is returned..

Comment: So F12 shows a completely blank HTTP response? There is no body? Content-Length is 0?

Comment: Is it blank the source.. however, i used the networking tool on IE and the status code is 400... surprised nothing errors came back though

Comment: See my updated answer. In addition to the UriTemplate problem, your binding is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, however, I need this to be a SOAP service specifically.so what I want to achieve won't work in SOAP?

Comment: Then you're confusing SOAP and REST. SOAP uses XML messages to send things, NOT the path/query string. WebGet is REST, not SOAP. Remove the WebGet, it serves no purpose for REST and generate a Service Reference instead of using WebClient,. You need to pass SOAP envelopes, not a URL path.

Comment: arghhh I see, sorry I am only half a day old usign WCF - so removing webget, how would I test it via a browser?

Comment: Just go directly to http://localhost:61094/Service1.svc and ASP.NET will generate a test page for you that shows the methods of your service and lets you execute them

Comment: Will mark as an answer for your all your help, and I believe the answer will benefit others. thanks again.